# Reading Integers into IntegerType array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

I am supposed to write a program that reads integers from a `txt` file in an `IntegerType` array. I have created an `IntegerType` class that implements my AnyType interface as you will see in the code. I am then supposed to sort the array and study how many comparisons and swaps were made during the sorting to study the efficiency, which I know is `O(N^2)`. I have set breakpoints in my code which showed me that the integers are being read into my String[] numbers array. When I try to add them to my `IntegerType` arrays, it hits the the `while (scan.hasNext())` line of code and completely skips over my for loop to add the integers into my array. Anyone have any advice on how to resolve this? Thanks for your time. Here is my code:

My `Sorting` class:

```
public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int type, sort;
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Ask user for data type of input
        System.out.println("Make selection by typing corresponding integer value and pressing Enter.");
        System.out.println("Select type of input:");
        System.out.println("1 = Integer  2 = String");
        type = read.nextInt();

        //Ask user for sorting algorithm desired
        System.out.println("Select sorting algorithm to be used:");
        System.out.println("1 = Insertion  2 = Selection  3 = Bubble");
        sort = read.nextInt();

        //Read in integer values from generated .txt files into corresponding integer arrays
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("descending.txt"));
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        IntegerType[] worstCase = new IntegerType[numbers.length];

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < worstCase.length; i++) {
                worstCase[i] = new IntegerType(scan.nextInt());
            }
        }

        scan = new Scanner(new File("random.txt"));
        line = scan.nextLine();
        numbers = line.split(" ");
        IntegerType[] avgCase = new IntegerType[numbers.length];

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                avgCase[i] = new IntegerType(scan.nextInt());
            }
        }

        scan = new Scanner(new File("ascending.txt"));
        line = scan.nextLine();
        numbers = line.split(" ");
        IntegerType[] bestCase = new IntegerType[numbers.length];

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                bestCase[i] = new IntegerType(scan.nextInt());
            }
        }

        if ((type == 1 || type == 2) && (sort == 1)) //Insertion Ascending
        {
            System.out.println("Insertion Sort / Ascending / Worst Case");
            Sort.insertionSort(worstCase, worstCase.length);
            System.out.println("Insertion Sort / Ascending / Average Case");
            Sort.insertionSort(avgCase, avgCase.length);
            System.out.println("Insertion Sort / Ascending / Best Case");
            Sort.insertionSort(bestCase, bestCase.length);
        }
    }
}
```

My `Sort` class:

```
public class Sort {

    public static void insertionSort(AnyType[] list, int size) {
        int compare = 0, swap = 0;
        AnyType key;

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            key = list[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            compare++;

            if ((j > -1) && (list[j].isBetterThan(key))) {
                list[j + 1] = list[j];
                j--;
                swap++;
            }
            list[j + 1] = key;
        }

        System.out.println("There were " + compare + " comparisons made.");
        System.out.println("There were " + swap + " swaps made.");
    }
}
```

My `AnyType` Interface

```
public interface AnyType { 
    public boolean isBetterThan(AnyType datum);
}
```

My `IntegerType` class

```
public class IntegerType implements AnyType {

    private int number;

    IntegerType() {
        number = 0;
    }

    IntegerType(int i) {
        number = i;
    }

    IntegerType(String s) {
        number = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

    public boolean isBetterThan(AnyType datum) {
        return (this.number > ((IntegerType) datum).number);
    }

    public int toInteger() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your issue is the file-reading loops, you can simplify your question tremendously by trimming away most of the code and focusing on those. It doesn't even have to involve your IntegerType, since an ordinary Integer would be the same for that purpose. Personally I'd be suspicious about the nesting of `for` inside `while` -- it looks like the latter should either be `if` or should be merged into the `for`'s controls.

Comment: @keshlam
I see what you mean, but when I tried that it still gave me a null array. I realized I can just do it this way;

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 

           { worstCase[i] = new IntegerType(numbers[i]); }

Answer (score 0):

I guess the file consists of space seperated integer values in one line.
Anyway you should use the Scanner.hasNextInt() methode, for checking.
So the problem is here (see comments):

```
    //Read in integer values from generated .txt files into corresponding integer arrays
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("descending.txt"));
    String line = scan.nextLine();     //reads already the whole line
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");   //now a string array with all the values

    //there is nothing left, everything is already stored in "line"/"numbers" variables
    while (scan.hasNext()) {   
        //something
    }
```

Since you do not now in advance how many integer values there will be, you need a dynamic data structure for your IntegerType values (f.e. an ArrayList). Or you iterate over the number array and convert every string value to an int:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("descending.txt"));
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = line.split("\\s+");
    IntegerType[] worstCase = new IntegerType[numbers.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        worstCase[i] = new IntegerType(numbers[i]);  //will work because IntegerType has a constructor which accepts a string 
    }
```

One more comment for your Sort methodes: They do not need the length of the array as parameter, you can just use array.length (but this is just flavor i guess).